# CSS hide previous element if :target

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide a previous element if an element is :target in pure css?

```
section:not(:target){
 display:none;
}
section:target{
 display:block;
}
section.main{
 display:block;
}

<section class='main'>
...
</section>
<section id='test'>
...
</section>
```

Now I need to hide section.main if #test is :target.

Comment: You can hide(affect using CSS) siblings not the parent, so as i see it's matter of sibling so **yes** you can.

Comment: Also target can not be used without `<a href="...">...</a>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your CSS

```
visibility: hidden;
```